# I want to make set of fields to be required if another set of fields are empty in yii2. Any one set of fields needs to be fill(required) perfectly

Tags: validation, yii2, conditional-statements, alternate

I'm working on admission form where, I need to capture parents information. So, there is a condition that any one parents data needs to  perfectly filled. Means if I don't fill fathers details then mothers all fields will be required. If I fill any of father's info field then, in father's details all fields needs to be required or vice versa.

This is my AdmissionForm model code:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      [['firstname', 'middle_name', 'surname_name'],'required'],
      [['residential_telephone_no',],'required'],
      [['father_name', 'father_qualification', 'father_occupation', 'father_mobile_no', ], 'safe'],//this needs to be alternately required 
      [['mother_name', 'mother_qualification', 'mother_occupation', 'mother_mobile_no', ], 'safe'],//this needs to be alternately required
      [[ 'admission_date'], 'safe'],
      [['form_id'], 'required'],
      [['aadhaar_no'], 'match', 'pattern' => '/^\d{12}$/', 'message' => 'Field must contain exactly 12 digits.',],
    ];
}
```

I just Want to capture any one of parents details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`yii\validatprs\Validator::$when`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#$when-detail) callback to specify whether the rule should or shouldn't be applied. The callback should return true if the rule should be used.

For example we can make fields with father's details required when mother's name is empty:

```php
[
    ['father_name', 'father_qualification', 'father_occupation', 'father_mobile_no'],
    'required',
    'when' => function ($model) {
         return empty($model->mother_name);
    }
]
```